# SyntaxError and "if is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The program is displaying: `"syntax error"` and `"if is not defined"`.

```
task = input (' select task 1, 2 or  3. Type  5 to exit\n')


If (task == 1 ) : 
    print "I am task 1! \n"
    print "I can tell you the sum of two numbers. \n"
    n = input ('input the first number \n')
    m = input ('input the second number \n')
    sum = n + m 
    print " their sum is : ", sum, ".\n"
```

Comment: `If` should be lowercase -- do `if`, not `If`.

Comment: You might want to try a lowercase `if`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of If (task == 1 ) :

you have to write "if" not "If". capital letter of "if" must be lowercase

```
task = input (' select task 1, 2 or  3. Type  5 to exit\n')


if task == 1: 
    print "I am task 1! \n"
    print "I can tell you the sum of two numbers. \n"
    n = input ('input the first number \n')
    m = input ('input the second number \n')
    sum = n + m 
    print " their sum is : ", sum, ".\n"
```

this will work.